# Ranked-Search on C# Collections

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, full-text-search

Is there a way to do a ranked "Full-Text Search" in memory on a C# collection? At any given point, I'd have under 50 objects in the collection, and I don't mind if it take a second to complete.

Anyone know of any libraries out there?

Comment: What does this have to do with linq? Wouldn't you just use `OrderBy(...)` and use some "ranker" to get an integer value back for each object? It sounds more like a "how can I do full-text searching in c#" kind of question.

Comment: You're right. Nothing to do with Linq. I removed the tag. Thanks
Just looking for a relatively simple "in-memory" implementation of fulltext search.

Comment: The answer really depends on how large those objects are. If each object contains a relatively small number of words, then the naive method (search for each word in each object's text) is going to be easier to implement and probably just as fast as a full-blown FTS implementation. Do you want it to handle stemming, common misspellings, etc? Do the objects change frequently? Do you want to use Boolean queries? Without more information about the nature of your data and what features you want in the search, it's impossible to give any kind of recommendation.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [lucene.net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/). While it won't directly integrate with your collection you can index things in memory using the RAMDirectory.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the library Bsa.Search.Core
This package implements fast object search in memory.

- [.Net Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bsa.Search.Core/1.3.12)
- [.Net 472](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bsa.Search.Core/1.0.14)

**Object search -**
where you can create a list of objects and quickly search them in memory

```
var selector = new IndexWordSelector();
var morphology = new DefaultMorphology(new WordDictionary(), selector);
var service = new HighlightObjectService(morphology);
service.AddRange(new HighlightObjectInfo[]
    {
        new HighlightObjectInfo()
        {
            StrongSynonyms = @"Elon Musk | E Musk | Elon M".Split('|').ToList(),
            Name = "Elon Musk",
            Id = "1",
            Type = ObjectType.Person,
            Weak = new HighlightObjectWeak()
            {
                WeakSearchContext = @"SpaceX | Tesla | Boring Company".Split('|').ToList(),
                WeakSynonyms = @"CEO| CTO | Founder | Musk | Elon |chief designer ".Split('|').ToList()
            }
        },
    });
var found = service.Search("Elon Musk. He is the founder, CEO, CTO and chief designer of SpaceX; early investor, CEO and product architect of Tesla, Inc. founder of The Boring Company");
//the service will find next object: Elon Musk|founder|CEO|CTO|CEO|founder
```

**Memory Index search:**

```
 var field = "*";

 var query = "(\"Elon Musk\" | \"E Musk\" | \"Elon M\")|((SpaceX | Tesla | \"Boring Compan\") ~10 (CEO| CTO | Founder | Musk | Elon | \"chief designer))";

 var documentIndex = new MemoryDocumentIndex();
 var content = "Elon Musk. He is the founder, CEO, CTO and chief designer of SpaceX; early investor, CEO and product architect of Tesla, Inc. founder of The Boring Company";

 var searchService = new SearchServiceEngine(documentIndex);

 var doc = new IndexDocument("1");

 doc.Add("content".GetField(content));

 searchService.Index(new IndexDocument[]
 {
     doc
 });

 var parsed = query.Parse(field);


 var request = new SearchQueryRequest()
 {
      Query = parsed,
      Field = field,
      ShowHighlight = true,
      OrderField = SortOrderFields.Relevance,
      Order = SortOrder.Desc,
      Size = 20,
  };
        var result = searchService.Search(request);
```